# "at" in "at the table"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

> This food falls into the category known as *nabemono* or *nabe*, traditionally made in Japanese earthenware called *donabe*, often on a portable burner **at the table**. ([source](https://www.wsj.com/articles/comfort-food-that-brings-the-whole-table-together-1525883404))

Why is the prepostion "at" used here instead of "on"? My understanding is that food is on the table and cooked on the table, people sit at the table. Why does the article talk about food cooked "at the table"?

Comment: "at the table" is just giving a location in the room. Could be "at the counter" or "at the back of the room". You could say "You can pick up your dessert at the last table" even though the dessert is actually *on* the table.

Comment: @user3169 This would make a great answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities.  Either the author meant

> This food falls into the category known as *nabemono* or *nabe*, traditionally made in Japanese earthenware called *donabe*, often on a portable burner on the table.

meaning that the "burner" (I assume the author means "brazier") is physically sitting on the table, or

> This food falls into the category known as *nabemono* or *nabe*, traditionally made in Japanese earthenware called *donabe*, often on a portable burner, at the table.

meaning that the action of cooking is done at the table, instead of in the kitchen.  Presumably the brazier is on the table, but that is not directly stated.

"At" means, effectively, "adjacent to", and might refer to a diner or a server, but not to something resting on the table surface.

**Edit:** I just thought of a third possibility: perhaps the brazier is free-standing, it is resting directly on the floor next to the table.  Alternatively, it is on a tray or cart next to the table.  Then it would be "at" the table.

Answer (score 1):

> **at** the table

is just giving a location (or some identifier) in the room. Could be "at the counter" or "at the back of the room". What's on the table is not mentioned.

So if you said:

> You can pick up your dessert **at** the last table.

it is telling you which table (location). It would be presumed that the "dessert" is *on* that table.